# Long running bash update script loop. How to handle terminating better?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, systemd, job-control

I have a bash script that downloads some data, runs a process to import it, then sleeps for a little while (about an hour). It's running fine as a systemd service (on Ubuntu 16.04 & 18.04)

*But* I am afraid that interrupting the import process could leave the database in an inconsistent state, so I want to prevent it being interrupted. i.e. `systemctl stop mything` should block until the import process is finished. Other steps in the process can be interrupted at will.

Is there any easy way in a bash script to run a command and say "don't propagate the `SIGKILL` signal to this command"? (`nohup` blocks `SIGHUP`). For other, similar scripts, I've used bash's `trap` to 'catch' the signal which stops bash killing the process, but then the `sleep` isn't killed, so I had to run sleep in the background and `wait` on it (and then kill the sleep in the signal handler). Which seems overtly complicated.

Is there a better way? Is there a `nosigkill` command (like `nohup`) which will block sigkill for just that command?

Comment: @anx Yes using a systemd timer+service could be better than a service...

Answer (score 1):

You can set [`FinalKillSignal=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html#FinalKillSignal=) to a different signal than SIGKILL, e.g. SIGCONT.

Note that systemd is going to get very annoyed at being unable to stop the service, but it should keep running.